# Google Cloud - DNS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, googledns

We currently have an on-site DNS server which manages what users can and can't access.

We would like to move this to Google Cloud, would this be possible? Or is Google Cloud DNS just for your own domain rather than a DNS server monitoring DNS requests and managing traffic?

Thanks

Comment: Be more specific on the DNS server you want to migrate. Explain what access control this DNS server is providing.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud DNS doesn't provide any DNS-based [blocking / filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_blocking) like  [SafeDNS](https://www.safedns.com/en/), [OpenDNS](https://www.opendns.com/) or similar solutions.

Have a look at the documentation [Google Cloud DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns):

> **Google Cloud DNS is a scalable, reliable, and managed authoritative
>   Domain Name System (DNS) service running on the same infrastructure as
>   Google**. It has low latency, high availability and is a cost-effective
>   way to make your applications and services available to your users.
>   Cloud DNS translates requests for domain names like www.google.com
>   into IP addresses like 74.125.29.101. **Cloud DNS is programmable. You
>   can easily publish and manage millions of DNS zones and records using
>   our simple user interface, command-line interface or API**.